# Advantages/Disadvantages of code location when accessing Resource file

Tags: java, constructor, attributes

Here are 3 options I have seen when accessing a resource file. 
Option 1 is probably the least recommended due to the potential of exceptions so the question really pertains to Option 2 or 3 as to which is the preferred or recommended implementation.

**Option 1** - done in the attributes area. Very generic. Doesn't capture potential exceptions.

```
class MyClass 
{
    static ResourceBundle bundle = Resource.getBundle("MyFile");
    float value1 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue1"));
    float value2 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue2"));
}
```

**Option 2** - access the resources within the Constructor. Since the values won't be dynamic it seems a waste to access them every time that class is instantiated as this class is a heavily used item.

```
class MyClass 
{
    static ResourceBundle bundle = Resource.getBundle("MyFile");
    float value1; 
    float value2;

    public MyClass()
    {
        try
        {
            value1; = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue1"));
            value2 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue2"));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3** - code within the attributes section of the class. I like this as its only accessed once if the class is already in memory, but since all the attributes tend to be at the top of the class, it does make the code appear all cluttered with try/catch and extra code.

```
class MyClass 
{
    static ResourceBundle bundle = Resource.getBundle("MyFile");
    float value1; 
    float value2;
    {
        try
        {
            value1; = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue1"));
            value2 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("myValue2"));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like its more a matter of preference than anything else as I don't expect the overhead difference to be measurable even if there were 20-30 resources being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 2 and 3 produce same bytecode. So difference is only aesthetical.